# How to paste transparent image into white background?

Tags: python, transparency, python-imaging-library

I have a code that looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open ("image.png")
image.putalpha (128)

background = Image.new ("RGBA", (1024, 720), "white")

background = Image.alpha_composite (background, image)

background.save ("newImage.png")
```

The problem is that the background starts changing tone, as the alpha I set to the image increases, the background  black, and as it decreases, it becomes white, so when it is 128, I get grey instead of white background.

I tried the same with a black background and there is no problem.

The image I want to paste is the same size as the background, but most of the image is blank, so i have a 146×147 image, inside a 1024×720 blank image.
The problem is that the whole background changes color, not only the part with the image. (I would post an image but I don't have enough reputation)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: This is how transparency should work. What did you expect instead? It might be a good idea to post a picture demonstrating the problem.